# Goniometric functions function in GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl

A geometry shader gives an output greatly different from what was expected.

The problem is most likely linked to strange behavior of goniometric functions I experienced.

When computing `S`, that is passed to the fragment shader, results for

```
float e = u - 3.14159 / 2;
float f = v - 3.14159 / 2;

float p = (- sin (f) * a - cos (f) * b) / D;

vec2 S = A + vec2 (-sin (u), - cos (u)) * p;
```

and

```
float p = (cos (v) * a - sin (v) * b) / D;

vec2 S = A + vec2 (sin (u), - cos (u)) * p;
```

are different, which they obviously shouldn't be.

Answer (score 3):

It is not obvious that the results are different. `p` is calculated two different ways, as is `S`. Algebraically they turn out to be different things.

Method 1:

```
S = A + vec2(-sin(u)*(-sin(f)*a - cos(f)*b)/D, -cos(u)*(-sin(f)*a - cos(f)*b)/D);
```

Method 2:

```
S = A + vec2( sin(u)*( cos(v)*a - sin(v)*b)/D, -cos(u)*( cos(v)*a - sin(v)*b)/D);
```

It looks like you're mismatching your `u` and `v` with your `e` and `f`.